# Since the normal distribution is symmetric, why *wouldn't* $Z$ equal $\sqrt{y}$ and $-\sqrt{y}$ with equal probabilities?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

My textbook, *Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang, provides the following example:

> **Example 4**
>
> Let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y = Z^2$. Find $\mathbb{E}[Y | Z]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z | Y]$.
>
> Since $Y$ is a function of $Z$, $E(Y | Z) = E(Z^2 | Z) = Z^2$ by taking out what's known.
>
> To get $E(Z | Y)$, notice that conditional on $Y = y$, $Z$ equals $\sqrt{y}$ or $- \sqrt{y}$ with equal probabilities by the symmetry of the standard normal, so $E(Z | Y = y) = 0$ and $E(Z | Y) = 0$.

My intuition is having a bit of trouble with the second explanation. Since the normal distribution is symmetric, why *wouldn't* $Z$ equal $\sqrt{y}$ and $-\sqrt{y}$ with equal probabilities? Naively speaking, it seems like the symmetry argument would be an argument in support of this fact.

I would appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this.

EDIT:

I just came across another example that seems to allude to the same fact as above:

> **Example 6**
>
> Let $Z \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y = Z^2$. Find $\text{Var}[Y | Z]$ and $\text{Var}[Z | Y]$.
>
> $\vdots$
>
> To get $\text{Var}(Z | Y)$, apply the definition:
>
> $\text{Var}[Z | Y] = \mathbb{E}[Z^2 | Y] - \mathbb{E}[Z | Y]^2 = \mathbb{E}[ Y | Y] - \mathbb{E}[Z | Y]^2 = Y - 0 = Y$
>
> Noted that $\mathbb{E}[Z | Y] = 0$ by symmetry.

Comment: Are you asking about the unconditional probability? 
It comes to my mind the fact that  $P(Z=\sqrt{y})=P(Z=-\sqrt{y})=0$

Comment: @RScrlli Hmm, perhaps I misinterpreted what the author is saying here? I thought they were saying that *because of the symmetry of the normal distribution, there is no value $y$ such that $P(Z=\sqrt{y}) = P(Z=-\sqrt{y})$, and so it must be that $P(Z=\sqrt{y}) = P(Z=-\sqrt{y}) = 0$*? But since the normal distribution is symmetric, it seems intuitive (naively, perhaps) that there does exist some $y$ such that $P(Z=\sqrt{y}) = P(Z=-\sqrt{y}$ and so $P(Z=\sqrt{y}) = P(Z=-\sqrt{y} \not= 0$?

Comment: I think that the explanation is much simpler, since given  $Y=y$ the r.v $Z$ can take two values $\pm \sqrt{y}$ with equal probability $p$. Taking the expectation is then nothing more than $p\sqrt{y} + p(-\sqrt{y})=0$

Comment: @RScrlli Hmm, how does one get $p\sqrt{y} + p(-\sqrt{y})=0$ from the expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

> Hmm, perhaps I misinterpreted what the author is saying here? I thought they were saying that *because of the symmetry of the normal distribution, there is no value y such that $P(Z=\sqrt{y}) = P(Z=-\sqrt{y})$, and so it must be that $P(Z=\sqrt{y}) = P(Z=-\sqrt{y}) = 0$*?

Nope, the authors are saying so such thing.

It sounds like you're reading this as a proof by contradiction, and so you're wondering where the contradiction is. But it's not a proof by contradiction.

The authors are simply saying that *as a matter of fact*, $Z$ equals $\sqrt{y}$ or $-\sqrt{y}$ with equal probability $\frac12$, so the expected value can be calculated as $\frac12 (\sqrt{y}) + \frac12 (-\sqrt{y}) = 0$.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.